# Get c# object list from response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am wroking on asp.net core web api and I am new in asp.net core. I make a web api and want to call it from web application controller and its works good. My problem is I want to convert json in c# object list. I already get a json format from web api, but enable to convert it into c# object list. I google a lot and find one solution in everywhere and that is

```
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusinessUnit>(result);
```

Which is not working for me. My Code :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "/api/BusinessUnit");
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
List<BusinessUnit> businessunits  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusinessUnit>(result); //result shows error because it needs string as parameter.
```

I am still trying but enable to solve this problem.
How can I convert "result(json format)" in c# object list "businessunits" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How the json string looks like?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya, it looks like basic Json format.

Comment: Your basic JSON format may not be matching the structure of the target object. So you might want to check the actual content of JSON string. If you can post the JSON string and the class structure here it will be helpful to figure out what fails the JSON deserialization..

Comment: Already problem solved bro, Thanks :), Below is the solution in answer sector.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to await the task like so:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Danger of using `var`, as now it inferred the type as `Task<string>`. If you had tried:

```
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It would have immediately given you an error that it can't cast `Task<string>` to `string`.

EDIT: The other error you have is that you are trying to deserialize the JSON into an object when it is actually an array.

```
List<BusinessUnit> businessunits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BusinessUnit>>(result);
```

Comment: The second one was an example of another error you can get. Did you try the first one as a fix?

Comment: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BusinessObjects.Models.BusinessUnit' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array."

Comment: Above error showing at line number 5 when I use "var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();"

Comment: That comes from JSON deserialization, it means you are trying to put an array into an object. If you are getting an array of BusinessUnits, you can do: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BusinessUnit>>(result);`

Answer (score 5):

In `.NET Core` this is done as:

```
var units = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<BusinessUnit>>();
```

Comment: only available in .net 5 and above

Comment: Nah, there are ways to get it to work in the older Core frameworks too, just takes more effort to do so: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1558

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
IEnumerable<BusinessUnit> result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BusinessUnit>>();
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hello, for that method "ReadAsAsync" you will need this library "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" from the nuget packages

Answer (score 2):

You can use .Result to convert in string :

`string XYZ = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Comment: This should be 
`string XYZ = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`